# Realm JS + Realm Android

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I have a Android application where some part are in Java and some in React Native. I am using same database for Java and React Native. Everything works fine but if I change data from Java during React Native is running then I can not get current changed data in React Native, this data are available after restarting React Native. Is it possible force reload Realm in Realm JS and Realm Android for get current data?

Exapmple:

1. run application, data are "foo"
2. change data in Realm Android to "foo1"
3. load React Native and load data from Realm JS, it returns "foo1"
4. on background in Realm Android I am updating data to "foo2"
5. reload data from Realm JS but it returns "foo1" but I exepted "foo2" <-- PROBLEM
6. close application
7. run application and load data from Realm JS and it is returning "foo2"

Thank you

Comment: I cannot find a `realm.refresh()` method in Realm-JS for some reason, so the best bet is to try `beginTransaction() cancelTransaction()`. It should trigger loading the latest data, but beware that it is blocking if a transaction is already in progress.

Comment: I can not find methods `beginTransaction` and `cancelTransaction` in Realm JS, but the idea is good. For Realm Java it works and if I change data in JS then in `realm.executeTransaction` the data are actual.